# Android creating and returning value from dialogs called from non-Activity classes

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I've built an Android application which calls a TCP socket related thread from six different activities. It works just and fine, but as I try to add a simple dialog witch asks the user's id/pw just before starting the thread(the retrieved data will be required in the thread), I'm having trouble. There is an adapter class which is actually called to start the threads, but it is also not an "Activity" which can implement a dialog.

Is there any way to solve this in some smarter method? Adding six same codes to create the dialog, and implementing additional six same handlers for each dialog will solve this, but I don't think that's not the right thing to do.

I tried to make the dialog an Activity(with a dialog theme), but it can't return any datas since the class which starts this dialog like activity is not an Activity(thus, startActivityForResult is invalid).

How can I solve this? Reforming the whole source is impossible, since it's over more than 20,000 line. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads which are not the UI/main thread cannot control UI elements like a dialog box. But there is a way to make a part of your code run on the main thread, and there you then can do such things.

You want to post something to the main handler like this:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable{
    public void run(){
        //Be sure to pass your Activity class, not the Thread
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        //... setup dialog and show
    }
});
```

Comment: Incredible! Will adding this code block on my adapter class solve the whole problem? I mean, do I require something more?

Comment: Well you still need to figure out how to get the information back to your original thread. I guess you need some public method which the UI thread can call to store the user's values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally figured out this easy issue.

To call a Dialog.show() on a non-UI Thread, I needed a Handler object created with the Looper.getMainLooper(). Then, just as @peedee explained, implement the things to do(UI related works) on the run() block.

Receiving the datas retrieved by the dialog wasn't difficult either. Adding some getter methods on my Dialog class, and adding an OnDismissListener before showing the dialog was all I required. (the OnDismissListener will react when the dialog's dismiss() function is called.)

Here's the code I wrote. Hope it might give help.

```
    Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("TESTRUNNABLE", "RUNNABLE LOADED");
            cDialog = new TestDialog(mContext);
            cDialog.setTitle("GROUP USER LOGIN");
            cDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    nameStr = cDialog.getNameStr();
                    pwStr = cDialog.getPwStr();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, nameStr + ", " + pwStr, 3000).show();
                    Log.e("DISMISSLISTENER", nameStr + ", " + pwStr);
                }
            });
            cDialog.show();
        }

    }, 0);
```